# SwipeRefreshLayout and TabLayout issue

Tags: android, android-tablayout, swiperefreshlayout

I have a simple project with a TabLayout in the MainActivity with 3 tabs, 
each tab has a SwipeRefreshLayout.

If I pull to refresh the first tab, then move to the third tab while the first tab is still refreshing, when I go back to the first tab it looks like there is a view over the first tab with a snapshot of the state of the tab before I moved to the third tab. I can scroll the items and use the tab normally.

Please see the images below and my code below.

I can dismiss the "refresh indicator" calling swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false); in onPause of ContentFragment, but the overlay view stays there.

### Initial screen

[image: Initial screen]

### Screen with the issue

[image: Screen with the issue]

#### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);

        PagerAdapter pageAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    static class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final int TAB_COUNT = 3;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new ContentFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TAB_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Tab 1";
                case 1:
                    return "Tab 2";
                case 2:
                    return "Tab 3";
                default:
                    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid tab position");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### ContentFragment

```
public class ContentFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerAdapter adapter;

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content, container, false);

        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }

    private class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);

            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.tvTitle.setText("Item #" + position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 50;
        }

        class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private final TextView tvTitle;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                tvTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_below="@id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### fragment_content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

#### recyclerview_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've found was to remove all the SwipeRefreshLayout views when the fragment view gets destroyed:

```
@Override 
public void onDestroyView() {
    swipeLayout.removeAllViews();
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```